# Do you need the front fan on Ender 3 Pro?

Tags: creality-ender-3, creality, cooling, fans

I have a heating problem on my Ender 3 Pro. I changed the thermistor and the 40 W heater but still the printer will just heat to 200 °C. So I unplugged the front fan that runs constantly, and, yes, now it reaches 260 °C.

Can I run my printer like this? I mean, it should have been mounted there for a reason?

Comment: Hi Felix and welcome to SE.3DP...

Comment: If your front fan stops the entire Hot End will heat up to well above 100C. Everything plastic on it will melt. I've had that happen.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, it is necessary.**

Its purpose is to cool the heatsink. The filament should only melt in the heater block. If the hotend fan is missing, the heatsink will also heat up, causing the filament to melt in it. This will cause heat creeps, which may result in inconsistent extrusion or unwanted clogs.

I once tried printing without a hotend fan and after a while, my filament got stuck at the height of the heatsink.

---

Your heating issues are probably due to other reasons.